# What exactly does segue.destinationViewController do?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

Hey guys what does this line of code do?

```
        AddRoleTVC *addRoleTVC = segue.destinationViewController;
```

I know the first part, with the `AddRoleTVC *addRolveTVC`, but i don't know what the `segue.destinationViewController` part does, i have found many different answers I'm just not sure which is the right one. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

In here the `segue.destinationViewController` points to the ViewController we are going to navigate to and is of type ‘id’.

Because we know where we are navigating to i.e in this case `AddRoleTVC` , we can treat `segue.destinationViewController` as if it were our `AddRoleTVC` and call methods on it.

That’s how we pass data from one VC to another through the segue by calling **set property methods** directly on our new ViewController i.e **addRoleTVC**.

Answer (score 1):

A segue is a transition from one view controller to another.  The destinationViewController is "another", the one being transitioned to.

The typical use of this property is to do some extra setup on the destinationViewController before the segue happens.  The from VC gets the message - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender.  Then it can grab segue.destinationViewController and do extra init, like giving it it's model.